# Deleting rows across an excel workbook with 31 sheets then joining the sheets into 1 df in pandas

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I have a workbook that has a sheet named 1-31 for everyday of the month.

What I'm trying to do is read the book with `excel_read()`, then delete the first 4 rows as it is header rubbish. I need to do this across all sheets.

After that I want to concatenate all the sheets into one data frame. I have limited access to the net at work which makes my life hard.

I know how to read all worksheets but not sure what is the `dict` name for the sheets. For example:

```
df.read_excel(filename, sheet_list = None).
```

I'm using Python 2.7.

I tried to using `del df.iloc[0:5]` but got an `AttributeError`.

Comment: Please show us the code you have been working on so far.

Answer (score 0):

No need to import and delete, just don't import it.

df.read_excel(filename,   **skiprows=4,** header=None)